# Why does the slice data type not store its length?

Tags: rust

```
let a = [23, 44, 45];
let a1 = a[..2];
```

Here, a is stored on the stack, why can the length of the slice a1 not be known if the length of a is known? Is it just a case of how the slice data type is implemented (a language design question perhaps), if so, why?

Also, when slicing a String, the slice uses a reference which points to the String which in turn stores a pointer that points to a heap location where the actual data is stored. Does Rust automatically operate on the data in the heap when creating a slice as opposed to operating on the String data that is referenced which is (pointer, capacity, length) stored on the stack (taking a slice of this seems like nonsense...)?

Comment: What is usually meant by "slice" is a _slice reference_, which you can create with `&let a1 = &a[..2]`. What your code is creating is an actual slice, whose size is not known to the compiler *in the general case*. In this case its size is obvious to you, but you could have also used an arbitrary expression such as `let a1 = a[..random::random()]`.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Yes, it is a type thing. The type of `a` is `[i32; 3]` so its type is known to the compiler. But the type of `a1` is `[i32]` so its type is not known to the compiler (it is known in runtime, of course). That is a *dinamically sized type*, (DST), so it cannot be stored in the stack directly. You know that the array is size `2` but what if you wrote `a[..x]` being `x` a variable read from elsewhere? The type of an expression should not depend on whether an expression is constant or not, so when slicing the length is erased from the type.

If you are sure about the length, you can restore the type information with:

```
let a = [23, 44, 45];
let a2: [i32; 2] = a[..2].try_into().unwrap();
```

About the slicing and the automatic heap, no, the heap is never automatically used, it just happens that a `String` is a head allocated type, as is a `Vec`. But slicing an array, for example, does not involve the heap at all.

When you slice an array you just get a slice of its data; when you slice a `Vec` or a `String` you slice the data in the heap, just because that is how the slicing operator is defined.